# Possible eager mmap page eviction MacOS

Tags: macos, paging, mmap

I have a program which accesses a large memory block allocated with `mmap`. It accesses it unevenly, mostly accessing the first ~1 GB on memory, sometimes the next ~2 GB of memory, and rarely the last ~4 GB of memory. The memory is a shared memory mapping with `PROT_READ` and `PROT_WRITE` backed by an unlinked file.

Compared to the Linux version, I've found the MacOS version is exceedingly slow. Yet, the memory pressure is low. (6.42 Used, 9.51 Cached.)

The following usage statistics originate from activity monitor:

- "Memory": 1.17 GB
- Real memory Size: 3.71 GB
- Virtual Memory Size: 51.15 GB
- Shared Memory Size: 440 KB
- Private Memory Size: 3.74 GB

Why is this? Is there anyway to improve caching behavior?